# Duplicate an object while changing one of its attributes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `CartItem` object that I want to make a duplicate of. Each `CartItem` belongs to a `Cart`.

I am writing a method that will take an old order and duplicate all of its `cart_items` and place it in the current cart.

`order.add_items_to_cart(current_cart, current_user)`

Order.rb

```
def add_items_to_cart(cart, cart_user)
  cart.update_attributes(merchant_id: self.merchant_id)

  self.cart_items.each do |ci|
    new_cart_item = ci.dup
    new_cart_item.save
    new_cart_item.update_attributes(cart_id: cart.id, cart_user_id: cart_user.id)
  end
end
```

Currently, I have the above. Is there a better way to dupe and change the attributes in one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If copying only attributes but associations is ok for you, then you are doing good. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Core/dup

But, I suggest you use `assign_attributes`, so you'll make only one query.

```
def add_items_to_cart(cart, cart_user)
  cart.update_attributes(merchant_id: self.merchant_id)

  self.cart_items.each do |ci|
    new_cart_item = ci.dup
    new_cart_item.assign_attributes(cart_id: cart.id, cart_user_id: cart_user.id)
    new_cart_item.save
  end
end
```

EDIT:

Make a method Cart#duplicate, which returns what you need

```
class CartItem      

  ...

  # returns copy of an item
  def duplicate
    c = Cart.new cart_id: cart.id, cart_user_id: cart_user.id
    # copy another attributes inside this method
    c
  end
end


# And use it
self.cart_items.each do |ci|
  new_card_item = ci.duplicate
  new_card_item.save
end
```

Comment: I want to copy the attributes and also the associations, but I want to point the associations to a different object.

Comment: You can create method `CartItem#duplicate` which returns what you need. I've updated code above.